# slideDown and Up for several <li> elements at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, slide

I am really stuck here at the moment and just wanted to know if somebody could think of an easy solution to my problem. I have several nested `<ul>` items with a few `<li>` in each and
I want the following to happen:

Whenever I click on one `<li>` item and it contains another `<ul>` it should slide down and show me all the list items and at the same time close the other lists on the same "nesting level". I tried to realize this but I really don't want to write some code for every possible constellation and I think there is an easier way.

For better understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/7zTc2/1/

Somehow the example is not working, but if you copy the content into local files it works. I did the first three lists and I want it to work like this for all the "child"-lists as well. If somebody could help me I'd really appreciate that!

Comment: It's not workin on `jsFiddle`, because you didn't select `jQuery` as a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day! Based on what I understood from your problem, here's how I did it:

**HTML Markup**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>value 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>inner value 1</span>
        <ul>
          <li>inner inner value 1</li>
          <li>inner inner value 2</li>
          <li>inner inner value 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>inner value 2</span>
        <ul>
          <li>inner inner value 1</li>
          <li>inner inner value 2</li>
          <li>inner inner value 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>inner value 3</span>
        <ul>
          <li>inner inner value 1</li>
          <li>inner inner value 2</li>
          <li>inner inner value 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>value 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>inner value 1</li>
      <li>inner value 2</li>
      <li>inner value 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>value 3</span>
    <ul>
      <li>inner value 1</li>
      <li>inner value 2</li>
      <li>inner value 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$("ul > li").has("> ul").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).find("> ul").slideToggle();
  $(this).siblings("li").find("> ul").slideUp();
});
$("ul > li").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me a lot of work. Seems like I have to study JQuery a bit more..

Comment: ok I dont know why, but I don't seem to be able to create a local file that does the same as the jsfiddle. I just copy everything into one file but it just doesn't work:

Comment: First of all, your call for the jQuery library from Google API is returning an error, saying that it failed to find that file that you're asking for. You can download the jQuery library yourself, place it inside your app directory, then include that file into your app. Second, you should use separate `<script></script>` tags to include the jQuery library and another pair of those tags where you place your jQuery codes. Lastly, place all your jQuery codes inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` so that they only get executed when the DOM has been loaded. http://pastebin.com/eDpmEMQX